# SQL Server : how to combine two select queries from the same table and take the result on Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot, union

I want to combine two queries on the same table that has group by.

Here is my table :

```
 Date#####   |  Value1 |  Value2 |   Value3 | Type
 ------------------------------------------------------
 23/04/2014  |  1,2    |    12,3 |    10    | Green
 23/04/2014  |  11,2   |    3    |   10,3   | Non-Green    
 24/04/2014  |  10,9   |    3    |    11    | Green
 24/04/2014  |  2,3    |    12,3 |    8     | Green
 24/04/2014  |  10     |    1    |    11    | Non-Green
 25/04/2014  |  10     |    2    |   10,8   | Non-Green    
 25/04/2014  |  1,4    |    5    |    12    | Green
```

The values are of `Decimal` type. Count the value1, value2, value3 >= 10. the expected result:

```
 Date#####   | Green |Non-Green
 ------------------------------
 23/04/2014  |  2    | 2
 24/04/2014  |  3    | 2
 25/04/2014  |  1    | 2
```

The value on green and non-green was from counting >= 10 of value1, value2, value3, here is my first query :

```
Dim strCommand As String = "SELECT d, LW, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 [date] AS d, [Type] as LW, SUM(CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt FROM tbBooth where Type = 'Green' GROUP BY [date],[Type] ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC"
```

It display :

```
 Date#####   | Cnt |Type
 ------------------------
 23/04/2014  |  2    | Green
 24/04/2014  |  3    | Green
 25/04/2014  |  1    | Green
```

My second query :

```
Dim strCommand As String = "SELECT d, LW, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 [date] AS d, [Type] as LW, SUM(CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt FROM tbBooth where Type = 'Non-Green' GROUP BY [date],[Type] ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC"
```

It display :

```
 Date#####   | Cnt |Type
 ------------------------
 23/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
 24/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
 25/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
```

I want to combine both query to become one, and take the **date**, result of **green** and result of **non-green**. Assume that I have a lot of group of date, I want it to display only the last 7 group of date based on `ASC` order.

Is there anyway how to do it? I tried to look on other SO post, like using UNION or PIVOT  but I don't have any clue how to implement it on my code.

Sorry, I already post this question yesterday, this is an edit with the expected result....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: check my query to get your output an easy way .

Comment: How many times have you asked this question?

Comment: @Mihai so many,,, hahaha... sorry, it doesn't a good result before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT d, 
       sum(CASE WHEN LW = 'Green'     THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) [Green], 
       sum(CASE WHEN LW = 'Non-Green' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) [Non-Green]
FROM
(
  SELECT [date] AS d, 
  [Type] as LW, 
  CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cnt,
  DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY [date] DESC) dr
  FROM tbBooth 
  WHERE Type in ('Green','Non-Green')
) x 
WHERE dr < 8
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY d ASC
```

Comment: Dear Clausen,
Thank you very much for helping me... I tried your code,, its work but it's only display some of the data...

Comment: @user3567963 after reading your question again I see your point, answer has been modified

Comment: @user3567963 I had some old of code containing order by in the inner query, it has been removed. It works now

Comment: Thank you for helping me... Your code works perfectly... thanks for always helping me...

Comment: dear t-clausen I found some bugs on my program. I use your sql syntax and it works. but it's only sort the date excluding the month, year. for example 09/05/2014, 20/04/2014, 21/04/2014. I used varchar datatype before, so I change it into date datatype but it give me different result when I display it on the chart. here is the result : 01/01/1914, 01/01/1936, 01/01/2002. do you know why it become like that? does it because the date store in the database including date(09/05/2014 00:00:00)?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: that is because you are using a varchar to store date. That is a big nono. You need to store it as date or datetime for several reasons. For your immidiate problem you should use convert in your order by. It will not perform fast though

Comment: yeah.. you're right. I already solve the problem by convert it to date. I am a bit confused why it's display 01/01/1914, etc... when I stored it in the date type column? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two case statements, one for each value; here I'm splitting the rows up in a common table expression first to simplify the cases somewhat;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT date, type, value1 value FROM tbBooth UNION ALL
  SELECT date, type, value2 value FROM tbBooth UNION ALL
  SELECT date, type, value3 value FROM tbBooth
)
SELECT date d, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN type='Green'     AND value>=10.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Green,
  SUM(CASE WHEN type='Non-Green' AND value>=10.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NonGreen
FROM cte
GROUP BY [date] 
ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecad3/1).

Comment: Dear Joachim,
your code is work.... But I want it to display only the last 7 row base on ASC order... in your code it display all the row... I added Top 7 on your code but it still display all the row... Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

try this one query instead of case when for every column...

```
Select *
From (
    Select [Date], [Type], COUNT(*) Cnt
    From tbBooth
    UnPivot (Value For Name In ([Value1],[Value2],[Value3])) As UnPvt
    Where Value >= 10
    Group By [Date], [Type]
) As GrpBooth
Pivot (SUM(Cnt) For Type IN ([Green],[Non-Green])) As Pvt
```

and out put is :

```
Date                    Green       Non-Green
----------------------- ----------- -----------
2014-04-23 00:00:00.000 2           2
2014-04-24 00:00:00.000 3           2
2014-04-25 00:00:00.000 1           2
```

Comment: if you like this query than give upvote and like answer. thanks in advance

Comment: your code also work... but it doesn't display when one of the green or non green is null or zero... thank you very much for helping me...

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to get your required output. Please check it out.

Please let me know if I have missed anything here so that I can correct it.

```
--Simulated your table
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
[DATE] DATETIME,
Value1 FLOAT,
Value2 FLOAT,
Value3 FLOAT,
[Type] VARCHAR(50)
)

--Entered values for testing
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, [TYPE]) VALUES('04/23/2014','1.2','12.3 ','10','Green')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, [TYPE]) VALUES('04/23/2014','11.2','3','10.3','Non-Green')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, [TYPE]) VALUES('04/24/2014','10.9','3','11','Green')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, [TYPE]) VALUES('04/24/2014','2.3','12.3 ','8','Green')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, [TYPE]) VALUES('04/24/2014','10','1','11','Non-Green')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, [TYPE]) VALUES('04/25/2014','10','2','10.8','Non-Green')
INSERT INTO @tbl([DATE], VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3, [TYPE]) VALUES('04/25/2014','1.4','5','12','Green')

--your required query
SELECT TOP 7 * FROM
(
    SELECT [date] AS d, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Green' AND Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Green' AND Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Green' AND Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Green,
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Non-Green' AND Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Non-Green' AND Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Non-Green' AND Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Non-Green]   
    FROM @tbl 
    GROUP BY [date]
)x
ORDER BY d ASC
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Dear samar,
Thnk you very much for helping me, I tried your code and it's work, but it display the last 7 row on Desc order,, I want it to display on ASC order, so I change the DESC to ASC, but it take the first 7 row instead...

Comment: I think I understand your problem. I think it is summing up only the first/last 7 rows and not all the rows in the table. I have updated my answer. Please check and let me know if it suites you. Please comment if it doesnt.

Comment: it still display on DESC order,,, example output from your code in : 24/04/2014; 23/04/2014; and so on...

Comment: It's already done... I change your code a bit,,, Thank you very much you really help me...

Comment: @samar this will not give the correct result when there are more than 7 different dates. It will not show the latest 7 dates